# vs code "go to definition" hope not go to the end definition

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

```
#define BIT(n) ( 1<<(n) )
#define A BIT(0)

void main(void)
{
    if(A == 0)
    {
    }
}
```

I want to see the definition of **A**, vs code will jump to **#define BIT(n) ( 1<<(n) )**
I hope vs code jump to **#define A BIT(0)**
there are any way to achive that?

Comment: The statements which starts from `#` preprocessor process them & preprocessor runs before compiler. So it will replace `A` with `BIT(0)` & then `BIT(0)` with `(1<<(0))` . Then code will compile & run when you execute.

Comment: Also If you are using proper IDE it should give error as `void main()` is prohibited by the C++ standard https://stackoverflow.com/a/204483/11862989

Comment: Actually i just want to know there are any way to change my vs code behavior. Just jump to the **A**'s statement, not **BIT(n)**'s statement.

Comment: No I don't know about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/8577) in the C/C++ extension, which (seems like) will be fixed in the upcoming release 1.10

Comment: Thank you. I test ok with the v1.10.0 C/C++ extension.